Insert as User fails during test class
We have a class created with sharing that inserts a record as a user. I've created a test class and added a user, along with the related PermissionSet assigned to that user. However, when I run the method under System.runAs(), the test fails to insert the record, and the error message is:

System.DmlException: Operation failed due to fields being inaccessible on Sobject Related_Con__c, check errors on Exception or Result!

My test setup:
@TestSetup
    public static void makeData() {
      Profile adminProfile = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator' LIMIT 1];
      User newUser = new User(
        FirstName = 'Testy',
        LastName = 'McTestface',
        UserName = UserInfo.getOrganizationId() + 'test2@example.com',
        Alias = 'testy',
        Email = UserInfo.getOrganizationId() + 'test2@example.com',
        ProfileId = adminProfile.Id,
        TimeZoneSidKey = 'GMT',
        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
        EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1',
        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
        IsActive = true    );
      insert newUser;
      PermissionSet ps = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = 'Services_Developer' LIMIT 1];

      insert new PermissionSetAssignment(AssigneeId = newUser.Id, PermissionSetId = ps.Id);
    }

@isTest
public static void test_my_class(){
 User newUser  = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Name = 'Testy McTestface' LIMIT 1];
 Related_Con__c controllerRelCon = new Related_Con__c();
 ApexPages.StandardController controller = new 
 ApexPages.StandardController(controllerRelCon);
 RelatedConCont ext = new RelatedConCont(controller);
  System.runAs(newUser){
      String expectedUrl = ext.save().getURL();
      System.assertEquals('/' + licence.Id, expectedUrl);
    
   }}

How should I address this issue to rectify the problem?

That's a custom error. Check your flows and Apex triggers.

Thank you for the respond, The test passes when I remove 'as user' from the insert line. Instead of 'insert as user newRelCon', using 'insert newRelCon' passes the test

@sfdcfox, not sure why you think this is a "custom error" - compare here. This discussion also presents a workaround. See for the same error message here too, again with a recommendation.

@FelixvanHove Oh. I just kind of assumed Salesforce wouldn't actually write a message like that. It seems relatively unprofessional compared to most of their other error messages. I learned something new today!

Thank you @FelixvanHove As a work around I added stripInaccessible and it worked but if I am going to give createable access to every user what is the point of adding as user. This is done because of security concern, so this is not really a answer to my question

I fixed this, apparently it was the permission issues on the fields in Related_Con__c object. In order to find the exact fields, I have created the new user and run the test on setup => apex test execution it gave me the which fields are inaccessible according to that information I added the right permissions to the 'Services_Developer' permission set and it worked.
